# How to use Git?

Tags: git

I am an engineering student who spends most of his spare time watching TV rather than coding. So basically I have zero experience with any kind of version control system. My understanding is somehow they make distribution of projects easier.

I was looking into [Blueprint CSS Framework](http://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/tree/master), liked it and downloaded from their Git project page. Now, I know Git does much more than providing a link on their website. So my questions are the following:

- How do I use Git properly to keep my Blueprint download updated? Say there is a new version, what do I do?
- Can I update all Git downloads at the same time? Say I have Blueprint and other projects downloaded on my Mac, how can I update them efficiently?

I looked into Git guide, but it's mostly for the people who have much more experience than I have.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I don't think the blueprint-css part is relevant. You just can't learn git from the manual. That's fine, and there's plenty of beginner tutorials to go at.

Comment: http://progit.org/ - "THE" e-book for GIT

Comment: Git has a fairly steep learning curve at first, but once you figure out what's going on under the hood, it's one of the simplest (and most powerful) SCMs out there.

Comment: I found this question in a Google search, and it help me find what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: lol, Looks like someone spitefully downvoted all answers but two. Including the OP.

Comment: +1 for watching TV like a normal person

Comment: I noticed the progit link doesn't work, here's a new link: http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: Hope you would have gained some other knowledge by watching TV..

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Have a look at [git for designers](http://hoth.entp.com/output/git_for_designers.html) for great one page article/high level intro to the topic.  (That link is broken: Here is a link to [another Git for Designers](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/git-for-designers-part-1) )

I would start at http://git-scm.com/documentation, there are documents and great video presentations for non-software-developer/cs users. [Git for beginners](http://www.spheredev.org/wiki/Git_for_the_lazy) have some basic stuff.

Comment: when you downvote you might leave some notes about reason why, or just provide better answer ...

Comment: It looks like the [Git for beginners](http://www.spheredev.org/wiki/Git_for_the_lazy) link is dead.

Comment: thanks @HeadofCatering I've replaced with another useful link

Comment: Link is still dead, as is git for designers

Comment: @stefanB I hope it's OK to just edit the Answer (added an alternate to a dead link). If not, let me know. (I figured it's easier to just ask YOU than to find the rule on this)

Answer (score 26):

I really like the O'Reilly book "Version Control with Git". I read it cover-to-cover and now I'm very comfortable with advanced git topics.

Comment: Now, why on earth would this answer get a -1 rating? You guys are discouraging earnest answers.

Answer (score 20):

**git clone your-url local-dir**

to checkout source code;

**git pull**

to update source code in local-dir;

Answer (score 7):

You might want to start with an [introduction to version control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/). This guide is specific to subversion, but the core concepts can be applied to most version control systems. After you have the basics, you can delve into the git guide.

Answer (score 6):

I think [gitready](http://www.gitready.com/) is a great starting point. I'm using git for a project now and that site pretty much got the ball rolling for me.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your questions directly rather than pointing you at documentation:

1) In order to keep it up to date, do a git pull and that will pull down the latest changes in the repository, on the branch that you're currently using (which is generally master)

2) I don't think there's something (widely available) that'll do this for you. To update them follow 1) for all projects.

Answer (score 2):

Using Git for version control

Visual studio code have Integrated Git Support.

- Steps to use git.

Install Git  : https://git-scm.com/downloads

***1)   Initialize your repository***

Navigate to directory where you want to initialize Git

Use **git init** command
This will create a empty .git repository

***2)   Stage the changes***

Staging is process of making Git to track our newly added files. For example add a file and type git status. You will find the status that untracked file.
So to stage the changes use **git add filename**. 
If now type git status, you will find that new file added for tracking.

You can also unstage files. Use git reset

***3)   Commit Changes***

Commiting is the process of recording your changes to repository. To commit the statges changes, you need to add a comment that explains the changes you made since your previous commit.

Use **git commit -m message string**

We can also commit the multiple files of same type using command **git add '*.txt'**. This command will commit all files with txt extension.

***4)   Follow changes***

The aim of using version control is to keep all versions of each and every file  in our project,
Compare the the current version with last commit and keep the log of all changes.

Use **git log** to see the log of all changes.

Visual studio code’s integrated git support help us to compare the code by double clicking on the file OR **Use git diff HEAD**

You can also undo file changes at the last commit. Use **git checkout -- file_name**

***5)   Create remote repositories***

Till now we have created a local repository. But in order to push it to remote server. We need to add a remote repository in server.

Use **git remote add origin server_git_url**

Then push it to server repository

Use **git push -u origin master**

Let assume some time has passed. We have invited other people to our project who have pulled our changes, made their own commits, and pushed them.

So to get the changes from our team members, we need to pull the repository.

Use **git pull origin master**

***6)   Create Branches***

Lets think that you are working on a feature or a bug. Better you can create a copy of your code(Branch) and make separate commits to. When you have done, merge this branch back to their master branch.

Use **git branch branch_name**

Now you have two local branches i.e master and XXX(new branch). You can switch branches using **git checkout master** OR git **checkout new_branch_name**

Commiting branch changes using **git commit -m message**

Switch back to master using **git checkout master**

Now we need to merge changes from new branch into our master 
Use **git merge branch_name**

Good! You just accomplished your bugfix Or feature development and merge. Now you don’t need the new branch anymore. So delete it using **git branch -d branch_name**

Now we are in the last step to push everything to remote repository using **git push**

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this three for beginners

http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial

https://tutsplus.com/course/git-essentials/ **(video tutorial)**

http://lifehacker.com/5983680/how-the-heck-do-i-use-github **(gihub)**

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to update several git repositories in one command - i suggest that you read a little bit on [repo](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/).

About updating the repository, you can do it by:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

OR

```
git pull --rebase
```

For more information about using GIT you can take a look on my [GIT beginners guide](http://www.linux-programmer-guide.com/guides/git.php)

Answer (score 0):

this is my blog on git and its for beginners who want to get started on git.
https://techxposers.com/git-for-beginners/