# Git tags. Concepts and best practices

Tags: git

First post. I tried researching my issue but I couldn't find a definitive answer. It's to do with Git which I'm learning and prototyping at work.

We'll eventually add our source and then start development using it and we'll do the usual commits, that sort of thing. At some point we'll mark the completed product using a tag, say 1.0. The development process will carry on and maybe we'll tag, say 1.9 at a future date. I think that's the approach we need to follow?

If it is, let's say a customer phones in and says there's a problem in 1.6 which worked in 1.4. What we'd think of doing is somehow getting all the code out of Git for version 1.4 and version 1.6. We could then run both folders in BeyondCompare's diffing tool, that type of thing. Also, if we get everything out for version 1.6 we could test it.

If you think that tags is the correct approach, then can someone advise me as to which Git command will let me go back in time and get everything that was tagged at the point in time?

Comment: You don't need an external diffing tool git already IS a glorified diff tool e.g. `git diff tag1..tag2` - I suggest general background reading on how to use git and using git before on a trial project. Yes tags are the right approach (though a tag is _just_ an alias for a given commit).

Comment: You can use `git checkout <tag>` to checkout exactly the source that made up that tag.  Also note that if something worked in 1.4 and is broken in 1.6, you can use `git bisect` to narrow the bug down to one commit instead of diffing the whole world

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't have anything resembling a programming question. Maybe it would fit on Programmers.SE?

Comment: @Useless ~~While almost certainly a duplicate of something~~ (it IS a duplicate of multiple questions), it's definitely about [software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004936/how-to-use-git)

Comment: I'm not sure how to target specific responses so here's a general flurry: AD7six, thanks for confirming the tags approach. Wolf5, thanks for for the other command references. I'm just more familiar with BeyondCompare. Forgot to mention, I'm working through Ferdinando Santacroce's book, Git Essentials. That's the source of all my Git knowledge to date.

Comment: @AD7six - true, but it's a general learning discussion rather than an actual problem. It's very subjective though, and I'm perfectly happy to be outvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Tags should be used to mark specific versions of your software, like a release; you can alway "go back" to a specific tag by using the command

```
git checkout <tag name>
```

I suggest you to read [this guide](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/03/tagging.html) about tagging and [this guide](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) about branching and tagging.