# How can two people work on a single project in Xcode on two computers?

Tags: xcode

As the title says. How is this best done?

I have done a lot of Googling but no luck

Comment: Use Source Control... Xcode natively supports git.

Comment: Use a version control system, check out two copies, merge on checkins as neeeded?..

Comment: @Gray Seriously? I just Googled your title and got a ton of usable answers.

Comment: http://www.git-tower.com/learn/

Comment: I recommend this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a version control system, like Git. You can create a free repository on [Github](http://github.com).

Some getting started links:

- [How to use Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1004936/3622606)
- http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
- Or natively in XCode: http://appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode