# Work from different pc's on a project located in localhost using phpStorm

Tags: php, localhost, phpstorm-2016.1

We are a team of 4 web developers working at the same time on a project located in localhost [each one of us has a copy of the project]. So what we are doing is using  a really primitive technique to upgrade it, we work on our copy and once per week we gather everyone's work, which is a HUGE HEADACHE. So I would like to configure phpStorm to connect to the team leader local server and work directly from there, so the project will always be updated.

Comment: use source control ( ex: git). Doing it any other way will cause a lot of issues as well.

Comment: @Dimi thanks but, no idea of how to do it, I've tried with file > Open URL... but it doesn't works

Comment: Download git gui tool(or sourcetree). Create a repo on one of your servers or host it on github. Git GUI tool should be able to guide you through the whole process. If Git GUI is a little confusing, try SourceTree which is a little bit more user-friendly.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004936/how-to-use-git

Comment: @Dimi, thanks just did it seems good stuff :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Abdul Rafay, thanks is good article to start, specially for me, given that didn't know Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend downloading git gui tool(or sourcetree). Create a repo on one of your servers or host it on github. Git GUI tool should be able to guide you through the whole process. If Git GUI is a little confusing, try SourceTree which is a little bit more user-friendly.

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier for all of you to create a Git Repository and collaborate your work.