# How to add codes in the bitbucket respository using command line?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am beginner for Bitbucket, I want to create and upload my codes in the repository, so I created one repository and then I tried to add my local codes but I am getting some errors like "selected folders are empty".
so how to add my codes into the repository? if any other ways are available for this process? and i need some basic command line for bitbucket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004936/how-to-use-git)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GIT which is Version Control System to add and update file in created Repo.

Assuming that you have cloned the repository below are the steps to add files provided you have access

`git add <filename with extension>` - to add files

`git commit -m <your commit message>` - to commit your changes along with messages

`git push` - to push your changes to your created repo.

Reference: 
1. https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/commands/ 
2. https://git-scm.com/docs

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or if they struggle with using Git terminal commands (like myself), they can use a Git GUI. [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is free, [Gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is free for non-commercial use.